Azure Site Recovery - Get Configuration issues messages
On the Dashboard for Azure Site Recovery (Home -> Recovery Services vaults -> MyVault -> Site Recovery dashboard) I see Replication health, Failover Health and Configuration Issues.
Under Configuration Issues, I see "3 Subscription quota insufficient". So, I click on that and it takes me to another window named "Azure subscription quota issues" and I see 3 errors, each with and error ID, error message and recommendation. How do I "get" these messages with powershell. I use Connect-AzAccount. So from there, how can I see those messages?
Here is an example:

Error ID 161015
Error Message There aren't sufficient cores available for family
'basicAFamily' for subscription '12345-12345-12345-12345'in the
location 'ukwest'. Current core limit: 10. Required cores: 24.

I can see quotas with get-azvmusage -Location "ukwest" and it shows me :
Name                Current Value  Limit  Unit
----                -------------  -----  ----
Basic A Family vCPUs 0            10      Count

But this doesn't tell me required cores are 24, or indicate any error.
Anyway .. I just wanna pull these kinds of messages from Azure with powershell, either with AZ commands or rest api.
thanks very much.

If it's still relevant you can get it via REST API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/site-recovery/replication-vault-health/get?view=rest-site-recovery-2024-10-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

Unfortunately, there is no direct command to obtain this information.
You can use the below Az CLI script to retrieve the required cores for specific SKUs.
$usage = az vm list-usage --location ukwest --query "[?name.value=='standardEDSv4Family']"
$skus = az vm list-skus -l ukwest | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    foreach ($sku in $skus) {
        if ($sku.family -eq "standardEDSv4Family") {
            $coresValue = ($sku.capabilities | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Cores" }).value
            Write-Output "The total cores of SKU name: Standard EDSv4 Family vCPUs is: $coresValue for $($sku.name)."
             Write-Output $sku
        }
    }

Output:

Reference: az vm list-skus
REST API : Get Virtual Machine
